# Web Service Call - Progress Bar with BackGroundWorker Not Working As Intended VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I am creating an application in VB.NET where users are able to attach XML via an OpenFileDialog and fire it at the Web Service.

I wish to have a progress bar at the bottom as at the moment, the GUI hangs and users think it has crashed while it is waiting for a response.

My code is below:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    For I = 0 To 100 'Telling the program to count from 0 - 200

        If hubURLtxtbx.Text = "LIVE" Then
            XStreamLive()
        Else
            XStreamUAT()
        End If

        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            'Telling the program to report the progress done by the ReportProgress
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(I)
            'Telling the program to stop after advancing one integer for 1 second.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

        ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ProgBar.Value = 100
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    BackgroundWorker1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Basically at the moment with the code as above the progress bar is updating AFTER I have received the XML response from the web service.

I want to have it so that the call is made and when the call is made the progress is updating, then when the call is successfully the bar is completely full?

Can anyone shed any light on this for me at all please?

Cheers,

James

**UPDATE**

OK so I changed some of the code and now when the XML is returned the Progress Bar max's out at 100 but it still freezes the GUI and does not 'increment' from the moment I click the button, it then fills the Progress Bar all in one go when the XML is been received.

**Updated Code**

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    If hubURLtxtbx.Text = "LIVE" Then
        XStreamLive()
    Else
        XStreamUAT()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

    If GlobalVariables.response = "" Then
        ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Else
        ProgBar.Value = 100
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing XStreamLive() and XStreamUAT() are where your upload is performed.  If so, you are running them on the GUI thread, not offloading them to the background worker.  This means the GUI will not update until the upload has completed.  As a side note, do you need the progress bar to actually show the percent complete, or just to indicate that the GUI is busy?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Subs into the DoWork of the BackGroundWorker and because the Service doesn't return a 'status' of when it is processing data I could return anything to my variables to update the progress bar.

So I decided to use the Marquee Progress Bar Style just to show that the GUI is doing something and then 100% it using the Continuous Style at the end of the process to show that it is finished.

J